# show email id in two lines

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am adding users in my project,in that I am adding username and email address.

User name is not compulsory, but the email is compulsory..
Email max length is 100..
My problem is:
when i am adding email and the email length is more than 60 then that email should show either in 2 lines or the space of that td in which I am showing email id that should be increased.
I want to show that email it next to ghost image.

I have done it through jquery as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".Email").each(function(){
            //alert($(this).text().length);
            if($(this).text().length > 55){
                $(this).css("margin", "-22px 0 0 59px");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are there any emails longer than 60 characters?

Comment: I think they are very rare people with an email so long .. put overflow: hidden in the email div?

Comment: Try adding some `max-width` with `word-break: break-all;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this in CSS alone. If you give the element which contains the email address width and set `word-wrap: break-word` on it.

```css
.test {
  width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipicingelit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [text-ellipsis](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) to truncate the overflow. For egs add below truncate class to your email element,

**CSS**

```
.truncate {
    width: 175px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.truncate {
  width: 175px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate" contentEditable="true">youremailsdsdsdsajdhjksahdkjsahkdj@gmail.com</div>
```

Or try the simple function for this in javascript,

```
function shortentext(txt, maxLength) {
    var ret = txt;
    if (ret.length > maxLength) {
        ret = ret.substr(0,maxLength-3) + "...";
    }
    return ret;
}
```